# $ _POST returns the original name of dynamically modified inputs with Jquery instead of the modified name

Tags: jquery, ajax, octobercms

i use jquery.repeater within several steps form manage with the October Ajax Framework.

the repeater have to change dynamically form input name like `my_input_text` into `my_group[1]my_input_text`, `my_group[2]my_input_text`, etc

when i use F12 in my browser, i can see input names are correctly changed as needed

```
...
<input class="form_input" type="text" name="group[1][amount]">
<span class="error_message" data-validate-for="group[1][amount]"></span>    
...
```

but within my ajax handler onSomething()  $_POST still return the original input field name `my_input_text`, so i can't manage correctly ajax errors return with `data-validate-for`

```
array:3 [
  "group" => array:2 [
    0 => array:1 [
      "amount" => ""
    ]
    1 => array:1 [
      "amount" => "666"
    ]
  ]
]
```

expected result is

```
array:3 [
  "group" => array:2 [
    0 => array:1 [
      "amount" => ""
    ]
    1 => array:1 [
      "group[1][amount]" => "666"
    ]
  ]
]
```

(the first array element is expected as it corresponding at the empty form used as repeater "template" with diplay:none)

here the jquery code which change input names attributes (and my hack to change `data-validate-for`

```
    var setIndexes = function ($items, groupName, repeaters) {

        $items.each(function (index) {

            var $item = $(this);

            $item.data('item-name', groupName + '[' + index + ']');
            $filterNested($item.find('[name]'), repeaters)
            .each(function () {

                var $input = $(this);

                // match non empty brackets (ex: "[foo]")
                var matches = $input.attr('name').match(/\[[^\]]+\]/g);

                var name = matches ?
                    // strip "[" and "]" characters
                    last(matches).replace(/\[|\]/g, '') :
                    $input.attr('name');

                var newName = groupName + '[' + index + '][' + name + ']' +
                    ($input.is(':checkbox') || $input.attr('multiple') ? '[]' : '');

                $input.attr('name', newName);

                $foreachRepeaterInItem(repeaters, $item, function (nestedFig) {
                    var $repeater = $(this);
                    setIndexes(
                        $filterNested($repeater.find('[data-repeater-item]'), nestedFig.repeaters || []),
                        groupName + '[' + index + ']' +
                                    '[' + $repeater.find('[data-repeater-list]').first().data('repeater-list') + ']',
                        nestedFig.repeaters
                    );
                });
            });

            //***** add by Pat-Och
            if (fig.errorMessage) {

                $filterNested($item.find('.' + fig.errorMessageClass), repeaters)
                    .each(function () {

                        var $span = $(this);

                        // match non empty brackets (ex: "[foo]")
                        var matches = $span.attr('data-validate-for').match(/\[[^\]]+\]/g);

                        var dataValidateFor = matches ?
                            // strip "[" and "]" characters
                            last(matches).replace(/\[|\]/g, '') :
                            $span.attr('data-validate-for');                        

                        var newDataValidateFor = groupName + '[' + index + '][' + dataValidateFor + ']' +
                            ($span.is(':checkbox') || $span.attr('multiple') ? '[]' : '');                        

                        $span.attr('data-validate-for', newDataValidateFor);

                    });
            }
            //***** end add by Pat-och
        });

        $list.find('input[name][checked]')
            .removeAttr('checked')
            .prop('checked', true);
    };
```

the issue is submit form don't retrieve right new input names but the originals ones.first, The repeater library clone the template as many time as user asked, then change input names then, after submitting, ajax handler see correctly template clones but with original input names

if run this

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
  console.log($('form').html());

});
```

the serialised form have original value and the .html have expected value, lost in the jungle ...

have no idea what happend beside and how to deal with this issue

Comment: To clarify, the `data-validate-for` message is not showing?

Comment: Surprisingly it works but in an anarchic way. For now I just put the required rule and the required message appears even if the field is filled

Comment: i "hack" jquery.repeater to permit it to change too the `data-validate-for` values as you can see here https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater/issues/60

Comment: the issue is submit don't retrieve right new input name but the original ones.first, The repeater library clone the template as many time, then change input names then, at the submit, my ajax handler see the clone but with original names

Comment: here a similar issue but this is for the input values, not name attribute https://www.willis-owen.co.uk/jquery-changing-form-values-not-affecting-the-dom/